# PHP reading broken images

Tags: php, image, gd

To save bandwidth, I am scaling images before downloaded to users (I would scale them     myself, but someone else is uploading them):

```
function scaleIm($I){
    $file="{$I['dir']}/{$I['name']}.{$I['ext']}";
    $img=imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
    $i_x=imagesx($img);
    $i_y=imagesy($img);
    $di_x=155;
    $di_y=155;
    $d_i=imagecreatetruecolor($di_x, $di_y);
    imagecopyresampled($d_i,$img,0,0,0,0,$di_x,$di_y,$i_x,$i_y);
    ob_start();
    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
    imagejpeg($d_i,NULL,100);
    imagedestroy($d_i);
    $i=ob_get_clean();
    return 'background-image:url(data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($i).');';
}
```

Since I am packaging all images together in one response, all images must succeed for any of them to display. When my colleague uploads a particularly large image on a spotty connection, we run the risk of the image becoming half loaded. At this point, the whole page fails.

I need to write an exception for a broken image. Return conditions I've tried:

```
if(!filesize($file))    //Doesn't work because a half-loaded file still has size

if(!file_exists($file))    //See above

if(!$img)
```

The last one seemed promising, but I think the failure point is at `$img=imagecreatefrom($jpeg)`.

Comment: Why are you scaling your images repeatedly? Scale it once, preferably at time of upload, and store a copy on disk.

Comment: Scaling images on the fly for each request is a huge waste of CPU. Cache the output of this function so that it only runs once.

Comment: Good point. Still, we're going to run into this issue at time of upload.

Comment: Nvm, I can just throw an error on upload. Also, would you suggest caching the base64 output?